# Dell D630 T7100 only 3 CPU Freq Steps

Tags: 14.04, dell, cpu

In my Dell D630 with a T7100 CPU i only get 3 FREQ-Steps : 800 Mhz, 1,2 GHz, 1,8 GHz but i want more as my other device with a T8300. How can i change it ?

I want to have 400 MHz , 600 MHz, 800 MHz, 1.0 GHz, 1.2GHz, 1.4 GHz, 1.6GHz and 1.8 GHz, i tried to edit the available freq table with

```
sudo gedit /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-1]/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

But it dosnt work, can anybody help me maybe ?

Distro: 14.04 LTS

Comment: Could you be more explicit? Where is the freq table located? (the [...] doesn't help).

Comment: sudo gedit /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-1]/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies

Answer (score 0):

You can not do what you are attempting. There are only so many performance states in any given processor. You can not just create new ones, it doesn't work that way. I have looked and looked and can not find the actual available pstate specs for your processor, but since the driver typically lists several more available frequencies, I assume the 3 that are there are all that is possible for that processor.